# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() Android Media Player

Tags: java, android

Am just trying to play music via Media Player for n secs.

```
public void playMusic(String music_path) {
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(music_path);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }, 20000);
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        Log.i(TAG, "Done Playing");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
```

My Function Caller from main file:

```
public void Play_Music() {
        mBtTestUtils.playMusic(MUSIC_PATH);
    }
}
```

Here when i do this i get the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling this on a thread different from the main (UI) thread?

Comment: @Juan Yes am calling from different thread.

Comment: That is the problem. You have to call it in the same UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions for your exception:

1) Call the `Looper.prepare()` before calling `mBtTestUtils.playMusic(MUSIC_PATH);` on caller thread.

2) If you are calling your function from different HandlerThread then you want to start your caller thread.

```
public void Play_Music() {
    // Starting of thread will prepare the looper (if it is handler thrad)
    callingThread.start();
    mBtTestUtils.playMusic(MUSIC_PATH);
}
```

3) Or while creating the Handler object, provide the main thread looper:

```
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // This will post your runnable on Main thread
        }
    }, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Looper.prepare()` first. Anything that you post on a handler goes to the message queue. A Looper loops through this message queue and sends tasks for execution. Whenever you define a new Handler, it takes the Looper of the thread in which it is defined. A newly spawned thread does not contain its own Looper unless you call `Looper.prepare()`, hence the error.
You can get a good explanation of this [here](https://medium.com/@swechhaprakash/understanding-handlerthreads-on-android-b7b842ab5cc4).